# How many threads are being used by this dispatcher?

Tags: scala, akka

I have a dummy `application.conf` as follows:

```
configuration {

  default-dispatcher {
    type = Dispatcher
    executor = "thread-pool-executor"
    thread-pool-executor {
      core-pool-size-min = 4
      core-pool-size-factor = 2.0
      core-pool-size-max = 8
    }
    throughput = 10
    mailbox-capacity = -1
    mailbox-type = ""
  }

}
```

So, there'll be 4 x 2 = 8 threads in the pool, always, and a maximum of 8 x 2 = 16 threads.

Now, if I understand correctly, dispatcher is responsible for picking an actor and a bunch of messages from the mailbox and processing them.

Next, I spawn just one child actor for a supervisor as follows:

```
val greeter: ActorRef = context.actorOf(GreetingsActor.propsWithDispatcher)
```

What I'd like to know is.. since there's only one instance of the child actor, only one thread from the pool would ever be in use.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a single actor can process 1 message at a time on a single thread. When the message is processed, the thread is returned to thread-pool, thus available for scheduling to other messages and actors.

Comment: a single actor processes `throughput` number of messages before relinquishing the thread. albeit, each of them is processed one at a time :) so yes, most of the threads in the dispatcher would be unused it seems :)

Comment: @LittleChild _at most_ `throughput` number, to be absolutely correct